# Feature selection on n different values

Tags: visualization, feature-selection

I have a `.csv` file with data in the following form:

```
moment_1;moment_2;moment_3;force_x;force_y;force_z;...
-0,02131267;-1,6032766088;5,9906811787;5,40010285;0,0203;86,44227467;...
2599;-1,70091039344;-1,3044809;-0,0406673590;-2,60896180797;43,2334;...
```

The file is very large and I need to put it in an interactive visualization, that's why I need to reduce the data points without changing the overall structure too much.

Many data points are very close to each other as seen in the following image:

[image: too close]

My approach was to define a threshold and filter all points which have a distance to the previous point lower than the threshold. But I think that's not an optimal solution because, when I remove one index, I need to remove it from the other data array too, otherwise the structure is changed.

Are there better approaches?

Comment: What are you using to process the data? Are you trying to reduce noise in the signal as well?

Comment: Currently, I just display the data in a visualization. Yes, I'm trying to figure out how I can smooth the data.

Comment: Have a search on dsp.stackexchange.com  It has more questions on smoothing  / subsampling. Is this from a gyro / accelerometer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of filtering single points I would suggest that you smooth your data using established techniques, e.g. Savitzky–Golay filter. Another option would be to employ Kernel Density Estimation, where you can then visualize the curves using a reduced, regular set of supporting points.

Comment: Thank you. I'm using Savitzky–Golay filter to smooth the data and Ramer–Douglas–Peucker algorithm to reduce the data points.

Answer (score 0):

You could try a linear filter like a Gaussian. It will smooth the data and has the property that no new local maxima or minima will be created (see Gaussian scale space theory).

However, I think a median filter (non-linear) may give you better results, as it will remove single spikes but preserve step edges. The kalman filter is also suggested in one of the answers here:  https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/4680/what-is-smoothing-in-very-basic-terms/4682#4682